# Make a python module accessible to everyone

Tags: python, upload, python-module

I've made a python module myself and I would like to make it accessible online (without having to create a website). Do you know any website that collects user-created modules that can be accessed by everyone for import? And if so, what is the process needed to upload it?

Comment: Learn about pypi

Comment: And also, from not that long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38100768/3001761

Comment: apparently deleted not long ago...

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking on PyPi

> **What is PyPI?**
>
> The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python programming language. There are currently 83402 packages here.

You can learn about it here: [How to submit a package to PyPi](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html)